# WP Query Foreach has infinite loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help. I can't figure out why this script loops infinitely b'se my site now keeps freezing the server ie constrains the resources to a point of shutting down my SQL server.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 4,
    'numberposts'     => 4,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => $id,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'        => '',
    'meta_value'      => '',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => '',
    'post_parent'     => '',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
$tips = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach( $tips as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array('itemprop'=>'image') ); } ?>
    </a>

<?php endforeach?>
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Anant, I've added the output. Pliz ignore the $i = 1, removed it. Thx

Comment: Much thanks let me adjust the <?php setup_postdata($tip ); ?>, Sure thanks, hope this fixes it all

Comment: This results to semantical error! Wrong output, seems has to remain <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

Comment: Works but the infinite loop issue in querying remains the problem, I have no syntax errors it's just the query constrains my server resources.

Comment: what is the output of `echo count($tips);die;`  put it just after `$tips = get_posts( $args ); ` and check

Comment: It's 4, am confused now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `global $post;` please add the following

```
$old_post = $post;
```

Then after the `endforeach` add the following

```
wp_reset_postdata()
```

and after that add

```
 $post = $old_post;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I haven't seen this before, hope it solves my puzzle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => 4,
        'numberposts'     => 4,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'category'        => $id,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'meta_key'        => '',
        'meta_value'      => '',
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_mime_type'  => '',
        'post_parent'     => '',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
        $the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
        if (count($the_query1->posts)>0) {

            while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array('itemprop'=>'image') ); } ?>
                    </a>
            <?php endwhile;


        }
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't give me any output however the idea of switching to a while loop may be what I'll do if this persists.

Comment: As you see in the while cycle you should get only posts thumbnails wrapped inside link, make sure you have posts thumbnails attached. or add `<?php the_title(); ?>` link tag after image. I'm using the same ode to show latest blog posts in home page https://i.imgur.com/hYriXBD.png

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is not closed properly, this is the reason its repeating infinitely.

Replace the last line of your code with this:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarun, the actual code is closing right. I just did the error here! I have no syntax error, it's just the query seems to be looping infinitely that it constrains my server resources.